# capturar el texto de una etiqueta vba

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo una consulta, es acerca de una macros que necesito formular, en ella necesito juntar la información de varias hojas de un libro en un único libro final, en esto no tengo problema, mi problema radica en que cada hoja tiene una etiqueta con texto, el cual debo capturar y colocarlo en la columna A antes de pegar la info de la hoja siguiente.

```
Sub hojas()

Dim i As Integer


    Sheets("WSP_Sheet44").Select
    Sheets(Array("WSP_Sheet44", "WSP_Sheet45", "WSP_Sheet46", "WSP_Sheet47", _
        "WSP_Sheet48", "WSP_Sheet49", "WSP_Sheet50", "WSP_Sheet51", "WSP_Sheet52", _
        "WSP_Sheet53", "WSP_Sheet54", "WSP_Sheet55", "WSP_Sheet56", "WSP_Sheet57", _
        "WSP_Sheet58", "WSP_Sheet59", "WSP_Sheet60", "WSP_Sheet61", "WSP_Sheet62", _
        "WSP_Sheet63", "WSP_Sheet64", "WSP_Sheet65", "WSP_Sheet66", "WSP_Sheet67", _
        "WSP_Sheet68")).Select
    Sheets("WSP_Sheet44").Activate
    Sheets(Array("WSP_Sheet69", "WSP_Sheet70", "WSP_Sheet71", "WSP_Sheet72", _
        "WSP_Sheet73", "WSP_Sheet74", "WSP_Sheet75", "WSP_Sheet76", "WSP_Sheet77", _
        "WSP_Sheet78", "WSP_Sheet79", "WSP_Sheet80", "WSP_Sheet81", "WSP_Sheet82", _
        "WSP_Sheet83", "WSP_Sheet84", "WSP_Sheet85", "WSP_Sheet86", "WSP_Sheet87", _
        "WSP_Sheet88", "WSP_Sheet89", "WSP_Sheet90", "WSP_Sheet91", "WSP_Sheet92", _
        "WSP_Sheet93")).Select Replace:=False
    Sheets(Array("WSP_Sheet94", "WSP_Sheet95", "WSP_Sheet96", "WSP_Sheet97", _
        "WSP_Sheet98", "WSP_Sheet99", "WSP_Sheet100", "WSP_Sheet101", "WSP_Sheet102", _
        "WSP_Sheet103", "WSP_Sheet104", "WSP_Sheet105", "WSP_Sheet106", "WSP_Sheet107", _
        "WSP_Sheet108", "WSP_Sheet109", "WSP_Sheet110", "WSP_Sheet111", "WSP_Sheet112", _
        "WSP_Sheet113", "WSP_Sheet114", "WSP_Sheet115", "WSP_Sheet116", "WSP_Sheet117", _
        "WSP_Sheet118")).Select Replace:=False
    Sheets(Array("WSP_Sheet119", "WSP_Sheet120", "WSP_Sheet121", "WSP_Sheet122", _
        "WSP_Sheet123", "WSP_Sheet124", "WSP_Sheet125", "WSP_Sheet126", "WSP_Sheet127", _
        "WSP_Sheet128", "WSP_Sheet129")).Select Replace:=False

            Columns("A:B").Select
    Range("B1").Activate
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight


>     For i = 44 To 129
>     Worksheet("WPS_Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = TextBox.Text
>     
>     Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido ¿Puedes probar una cosa al menos y cuando bloqueas la edición y vuelvo?

Comment: no entendí tu  comentario

Comment: Sí, lo siento Era solo para saber lo que ya habías probado.

Comment: use     For i = 44 To 129
    Worksheets("WSP_Sheet" & i).Range("a1").Value = TextBox1.Value

        Next

Comment: cual podría ser el código que me permita capturar el texto de un textbox?

Comment: E editado la macro que uso pero me sale eror

Comment: "Cada hoja tiene una etiqueta con texto, que debo capturar y colocar en la columna A antes de pegar la información en la página siguiente". No comprendo. Cada hoja tiene un nombre diferente y quieres poner su nombre en la columna A? ¿Y qué información quieres poner en la página siguiente? El nombre de la hoja? ¿Tienes un ejemplo gráfico?

Comment: No estaria entendiendo ni tu problema, ni lo que hace la macro, ni a que queres llegar. podes poner un ejemplo?

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con lo que ha dicho @gbianchi. No entiendo qué quieres hacer con ese código ni qué problema estás haciendo. ¿Seleccionar una etiqueta? ¿Te refieres a un control de formulario tipo Label?

Comment: Ok tratare de ser más claro con lo que necesito, Yo tengo un libro que cuenta con más de 150 hojas cada una con un nombre en particular, en cada hoja a partir de la hoja WSP_Sheet44 tengo un textbox con algunos datos relacionados a la tabla que contiene cada hoja, lo que necesito es primero adicionar 2 columnas al inicio y colocar los datos que tengo en cada textbox en la columna A y la columna B que inserte, esto lo tengo que hacer desde la hoja WPS_Sheet44 hasta la última que es la WPS_Sheet129, espero haber podido aclarar lo que necesito, gracias por su apoyo

Comment: me ayudarian mucho con el código que me permita capturar parte del texto de cada textbox y colocarlo en la celda a1 de cada hoja. Gracias

Comment: ¿Cada hoja a partir de  WPS_Sheet44 tienen una única caja de texto llamado Textbox1? ¿Todas las hojas se llaman  WPS_Sheet y un número?

Comment: es correcto cada hoja tiene una sola texbox y en cada hoja se llama texbox 1 y cada hoja tiene el nombre WPS_Sheet y un número que va desde el 44 hasta el 129. Agradezco tu apoyo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, creo que entiendo lo que dices.

Dentro de tu bucle FOR, borra la parte que dice:

```
Worksheet("WPS_Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = TextBox.Text
```

y prueba con esto:

```
Worksheets("WPS_Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Sheets("WPS_Sheet" & i).OLEObjects("TextBox 1").Object.Text
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** Tras ver el archivo del usuario, se comprobó que el control no era ni un textbox ni una label, sino una forma (shape). Además, todas las hojas empiezan por las iniciales *WSP* y no *WPS*, produciendo el `Error 9 subíndice fuera de intervalo`. Porque se estaba llamando a una hoja que no existe.

```
For i = 44 To 129 Step 1
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WSP_Sheet" & i).Cells(1, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("WSP_Sheet" & i).Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Caption
Next i
```

Comprobado en mi ordenador y ejecutado sin errores :)

Comment: Gracias por responder, he realizado el cambio que me sugeriste y me sale un error '9' en tiempo de ejecución.

Comment: Ese error es que se está intentando seleccionar un objeto que no existe. Es decir, o bien está intentando seleccionar una hoja que no se llama así, o bien en alguna hoja, la TextBox no se llama `TextBox1`. Vas a tener que comprobar hoja por hoja todo. Depura el código con F8 y mira en qué momento exacto falla.

Comment: Ya revise cada hoja pero todas tienen el nombre de "TextBox 1" así como lo escribo, de forma separada, tal ves no me se expresar bien con la pregunta, quisiera saber si puedo enviarte un archivo de prueba para ver si puede quedar mejor explicado, por favor es algo que hasta el momento no he podido solucionar y necesito tu ayuda.  Gracias.

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta. Prueba con lo que he puesto

Comment: Aún me sale el mensaje de error en tiempo de ejecución (subindice fuera del intervalo)

Comment: ¿Te sigue saliendo el mismo error? ¿en qué hoja te da error dentro del bucle? ¿O falla a la primera? He intentado evitar ver el archivo, pero si lo subes a algún sitio, a lo mejor encontramos alguna solución, aunque empiezo a quedarme sin ideas.

Comment: Desde el inicio me da ese error, no se donde lo podría colgar para poder enviartelo, creo que podría ser qe no me explico bien

Comment: Súbemelo a mi Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15F4qws2YiRJrsYAQHTaSx-TVPcRK_qpq?usp=sharing Puede que te pida iniciar sesión con una cuenta gmail. Cuando lo tengas subido, escríbeme por aquí, a ver si podemos hacer algo. PRefiero hacerlo así, por no publicar aquí direcciones de e-mail, y que algún robot la rastree y me spamee.

Comment: Ok te entiendo, ya lo subi al drive, ojala puedas ayudarme, muchas gracias por tu apoyondo.

Comment: Ya me ha llegado. En cuanto pueda, le hecho un vistazo y te cuento.

Comment: Gracias por el apoyo

Comment: Hola @INVEST_EXCEL. Ya tienes la respuesta correcta. Mira la actualización. Usabas un nombre de hojas incorrecto (en tu bucle for tienes escrito WPS en vez de WSP, la S y la P estaban mal). Además, lo que tienes insertado son formas, no textboxes ni labels. Entonces, hay que usar propiedades de los objetos [Shape](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-object-excel). Pruebalo y me cuentas, aunque a mí me ha funcionado.

Comment: muchas gracias, ya obtuve el resultado que estaba necesitando +1